# set value for input type text and save that value in mysql table

Tags: php

This is my html code...

```
<tr>
    <td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span style="color:red; padding-right:3px;">*</span>Cast
    </td>

    <td>
        <input  type="text" name="cast" id="cast" value="BRAHMAN" disabled/>                                        
    </td>

</tr>
```

I want to insert that value in database. I tried that but it inserting blank value in database. So How do I do this??

Comment: disable value  not  submit remove the disable.

Comment: More detail: where is the code which links to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your field is `disabled`

ELements with Disabled attribute are not submitted or you can say their values are not posted.

Use `readonly` instead if you do not let users to edit them.

```
<input  type="text" name="cast" id="cast" value="BRAHMAN" disabled/>
```

Remove `disabled` and add `readonly`:

```
<input  type="text" name="cast" id="cast" value="BRAHMAN" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Comment: I want to set default value for that field and user cannot edit that value.

Comment: Answer updated, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Html Code:

```
<input type="text" data-required="true" name="cast" id="cast" value="BRAHMAN">
```

PHP Insert Code:

```
<input type="text" data-required="true" name="cast" id="cast" value="<?php $_POST['cast'];?>">
```